# unable to enter data in mysql using php jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My mistake friends...below is the complete code
I am writing a jquery php bases register form code. it seems code is working fine but i am unable to enter data in mysql database. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Below is form:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="home_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
      var str = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax(
         {
         type: "POST",
        url:"contact.php",
        data: str,
        success:function(result)
                {
                $("#div1").html(result);
                }
         });
     return false;
     });
 });
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="contact_form">  
<form id="ajax-contact-form" name="contact" action=""> 
<fieldset>
    <div class="field_container">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_firstname" id="firstname"  maxlength="50" onblur="fnamevalidation()" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="50" onblur="lnamevalidation()" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />


<div class="sex_check" >
<input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
<input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="F" /> Female


<hr class="line_break">

<div class="field_container">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_email" id="email"  maxlength="100" onblur="emvalidation()" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='cust_password' id='password'  maxlength="12" onblur="pwordvalidation()" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Confirm Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='cust_password2' id='confirmpassword'  maxlength="12" onblur="cpwordvalidation()" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />




<INPUT class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">

 </fieldset>  
</form>
</div> 

<div id="div1">
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

and contact.php is

```
<?php
ob_start();

    session_start();

    require_once("config.php");




    $cust_firstname = stripslashes($_POST['cust_firstname']);

        $cust_lastname=stripslashes($_POST['cust_lastname']);

        $cust_sex=$_POST['cust_sex'];

    $cust_email=stripslashes($_POST['cust_email']);

    $cust_password=stripslashes($_POST['cust_password']);

    $cust_password2=stripslashes($_POST['cust_password2']);






// Get values from form



    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 

{

    // Insert data into mysql 

        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE cust_email = '$cust_email'");

            if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0)

                    {

                    echo 'That email is already registered';

                    exit;

                    }

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (`cust_firstname`,`cust_lastname`, `cust_sex`, `cust_email`, `cust_password`) 

            VALUES

            ('$cust_firstname', '$cust_lastname', '$cust_sex', '$cust_email', '$cust_password')");

            $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $cust_email;


    }




    echo $cust_firstname;

    echo $cust_lastname;

    echo $cust_sex;

    echo $cust_email;

    echo $cust_password;

    echo $cust_password2;



    ?>
```

Comment: i don't see where you are using jquery.

Comment: Check your HTML markup. It is totally invalid. That is going to cause some serious problems. For example, you can't close a `<div>` with `</label>`.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a little?

Comment: I edited the code.. pls look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the code in your PHP file that says `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))`. For one, your button name is 'submit' (with a lowercase s) and two, that variable does not get send so it will never be true. Then it should work. But I recommend to look at your HTML markup. It is totally invalid.

Comment: thanks mate it worked..please let me know where do u feel is the problem with html markup. i will correct it

Comment: Put your HTML trough a validator like http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and you will see.